# Django - Account Settings BooleanField

Tags: django

I reviewed most of the posts here related to Django and BooleanField update, but I couldn't find any related to my problem solution. 
I have a custom user models.py:

```py
# Own custom user model
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    guardianSource = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    bbcSource = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    independentSource = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    categoryCoronaVirus = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    categoryPolitics = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    categorySport = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

When I register a user it seems to register in the database all correct values for the checkboxes. The problem is when I want to edit user information I cannot see if a checkbox was checked on registering or not, it displays the checkboxes itself, but they are all empty (False). However, it correctly requests the username and displays it so I can edit it, but all the checkboxes are unchecked. 
views.py:

```py
def account_view(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('login')
    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = AccountUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            context['success_message'] = "Updated"
    else: # Display the saved user details from database
        form = AccountUpdateForm(
                                initial = {
                                'username':request.user.username,
                                "guardianSource": request.user.guardianSource,
                                "bbcSource": request.user.bbcSource,
                                "independentSource": request.user.independentSource,

                                "categoryCoronaVirus": request.user.categoryCoronaVirus,
                                "categoryPolitics": request.user.categoryPolitics,
                                "categorySport": request.user.categorySport,
                                            })
    context['account_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'accounts/account.html', context)
```

account html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<form class="form-signin" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Account Settings</h1>

  <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
  <input type="text"   name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"   value="{{account_form.initial.username}}">
    <br>
   <div  class="form-control">
      <p><b>Please choose news sources!</b></p>

      <label for="guardianSource" >The Guardian</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="guardianSource" id="guardianSource" value="{{account_form.initial.guardianSource}}" >
    <br>
      <label for="bbcSource" >BBC News</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="bbcSource" id="bbcSource" value="{{account_form.initial.bbcSource}}" >
    <br>
      <label for="independentSource" >The Independent</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="independentSource" id="independentSource" value="{{account_form.initial.independentSource}}" >
  </div>
    <br>
    <div  class="form-control">
      <p><b>Please choose news category!</b></p>

      <label for="categoryCoronaVirus" >The Guardian</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="categoryCoronaVirus" id="categoryCoronaVirus" value="{{account_form.initial.categoryCoronaVirus}}" >

    <br>

      <label for="categoryPolitics" >BBC News</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="categoryPolitics" id="categoryPolitics" value="{{account_form.initial.categoryPolitics}}" >
    <br>

      <label for="categorySport" >The Independent</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="categorySport" id="categorySport" value="{{account_form.initial.categorySport}}">

  </div>

    {% for field in registration_form %}
        <p>
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <p sttle="color:red"> {{ error }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if registration_form.non_field_errors %}
        <div style="color:red;">
                <p>{{registration_form.non_field_errors}}</p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% for field in account_form %}
        <p>
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <p sttle="color:red"> {{ error }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if account_form.non_field_errors %}
        <div style="color:red;">
                <p>{{account_form.non_field_errors}}</p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if success_message %}
     <p style = "color: green; text-align:center;">{{success_message}}</p>
    {% endif %}
    <h6 class="text-muted">
      If you don't choose a source and category it will automatically assign the ones that are checked!<br>
     NOTE: You <b>MUST</b> select at least 1 choice for each!!!
  </h6>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Save Changes</button>

</form>
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <a class="m-auto" href="{% url 'password_change' %}">Change password</a>
</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

Thanks in advance and I am sorry if my post is duplicated.

EDIT: 
The issue was found. 
In the account.html file  the values for each input type checkbox were wrong. 
What I changed from:

```py
<input type="checkbox" name="guardianSource" id="guardianSource" value="{{account_form.initial.guardianSource}}" >
```

To:

```py
<input type="checkbox" name="guardianSource" id="guardianSource" value="{{account_form.guardianSource}}" >
```

For all the input values after the username input the `initial` had to be removed

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass initial when you are initializing a ModelForm and have the instance

```
else: # Display the saved user details from database
    form = AccountUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
```

You can use the field directly in the template and it will be rendered with the correct values, you don't need to construct the html for the input yourself

```
  <label for="{{ account_form.guardianSource.id_for_label }}">The Guardian</label>
  {{ account_form.guardianSource }}
```

The docs have a section on how to [render fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found the error just before you posted the answer. However, your post provides more information about why it doesn't need the initial value. Regards